# Sphinx linking functions between files

Tags: python, hyperlink, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I've been looking for an answer on stackoverflow and in official docs and still can't find the solution.

In the main Sphinx-doc document I have:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::

    views/index.rst
    db/index.rst
```

In views/index.rst

```
.. py:currentmodule:: app.views
.. py:function:: create_user

  this function uses create_user_db
```

and in db/index.rst

```
.. py:currentmodule:: app.db

.. py:function:: create_user_db
   this function creates the user in database
```

What I need is a hyperlink from create_user to exacly the place create_user_db is.

Functions are not genereated by autodoc, I don't want to use sections and *.. _section_label :* for every function that is listed in db/index.

Is it even possible to link it that way that views can move you to db/index.html#app.db.create_user_db using :doc:, :ref: or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
this function uses :py:func:`app.db.create_user_db`
```

You need to use the fully qualified name.

Comment: If you want to omit 'app.db', place the following code before your link. `.. currentmodule:: app.db`